# How to calculate X days ago in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

In my application I am accessing a remote URL and getting a JSON response like below. The JSON response has a property called `created_at`.

In JavaScript I need to get the current date minus(-) the `created_at` date and calculate how many days ago the comment was created.

How can I do that?

```
{  
   "id":12578834,
   "title":"Joint R&D Has Its Ups and Downs",
   "url":"http://semiengineering.com/joint-rd-has-its-ups-and-downs/",
   "num_points":1,
   "num_comments":0,
   "author":"Lind5",
   "created_at":"9/26/2016 2:28"
}
```

Comment: You don't need a guide - you have everything you need: `"i need to get the current date minus(-) this created_at date and calculate how many X days ago the comment was created"`. Convert that English into JS.

Comment: try http://momentjs.com

Comment: @Mehmet I doubt anyone needs a library for a simple subtraction.

Comment: It is a lightweight library and you can use it for all date operations.

Comment: @shomz i have trouble in creating a date object with the created_at string and do subtraction

Comment: May be helpful - see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832341/741251

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create days and then get difference by subtracting `today.getTime() - date.getTime()/NumOfMSecInDay`.

Also, time part can cause some issues, so its better to strip it.

```js
var d = {
  "id": 12578834,
  "title": "Joint R&D Has Its Ups and Downs",
  "url": "http://semiengineering.com/joint-rd-has-its-ups-and-downs/",
  "num_points": 1,
  "num_comments": 0,
  "author": "Lind5",
  "created_at": "9/26/2016 2:28"
}

var today = new Date();
var createdOn = new Date(d.created_at);
var msInDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

createdOn.setHours(0,0,0,0);
today.setHours(0,0,0,0)

var diff = (+today - +createdOn)/msInDay
console.log(diff)
```

---

Edit:

As per [@picacode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5069866/picacode), `date.getTime` is faster than `+date`. Following is a [JSPer Link](https://jsperf.com/new-date-timing)

Comment: I think you don't  need setHours call

Comment: @mplugjan, thanks and apologies for incorrect name

Comment: @maheshiv if your createdon was say `9/26/22016 20:30` and you check it at `11/24/2016 5:30` will yield `58` and `11/24/2016 21:30` will yield `59`. Hence `setHours` is required

Comment: @maheshiv - always a good idea to normalise the time. If today is DST and daysago is not, then you may get issues

Comment: I thought we can concatenate ':00'  at the end and pass to Date function. But I agree with @mplungjan.

Comment: Why there are plus signs before the dates?

Comment: @picacode Thats is a shorthand for `date.getTime()`

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, I was looking into it and found out it was just turning it into a number and performance-wise it is slower than just doing `date.getTime()` I have editted the answer. For the performance test, you can check this link https://jsperf.com/new-date-timing

Comment: @picacode Your JSPerf is not up to mark. I'll make a similar one which only compares `getTime` vs `+date`. Also, difference is so small, it can be ignored

Comment: @Rajesh you are right it is just 10 percent faster but anyways it is faster and more readable in my opinion. Thanks for the code.