# Days/Weeks ago from specific date with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

I work with **moment.js** and I have 3 different dates, e.g.

- 30.07.2018
- 12.06.2018
- 10.05.2018

I now try to get the difference in days from these dates until today (if it is less then 7 days ago) or the weeks until today (if it more than 7 days ago) and place it in several spans.

**UPDATE** *thanks Thomas!*

I got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timestamp').html((index, html) => {

        let date = moment(html, "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm", true), 
        now = moment(),
        days = Math.floor(Math.abs(date - now) / 86400000), 
        weeks = Math.floor(days/7),
        result = date.format("DD.MM.YYYY") + " - ";

      if(weeks){
        result += weeks + (weeks===1? " week ": " weeks ");
        days = days % 7;        
      }

      if(days || weeks===0){
        result += days + (days === 1? " day": " days");
      }

      return result;
    });

});
```

What I still need:

- Not showing the initial date, just showing `"3 Days"`. If it delete "result", I want work anymore.
- Not showing `"7 weeks 2 days"`, this should just be `"7 weeks"`

Here is the actual [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r289hvpL/16/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r289hvpL/

Comment: @Thomas thank you so much! Just 2 little things. I don't want to have the output of "DD.MM.YYYY -" only "3 days" is perfect. Second "7 Weeks 2 days" should just be "7 Weeks". Could you help me again?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r289hvpL/21/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with momentjs **[`diff()` method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)**, which can return the difference between two `dates` in `days`, `weeks`, `months`, `hours`, `minutes`, ... based on the option you pass to it.

This is how should be your code:

```
now = moment()
days = now.diff(date, "days")
weeks = now.diff(date, "weeks")
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timestamp').html((index, html) => {

    let date = moment(html, "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm", true),
      now = moment(),
      days = now.diff(date, "days"),
      weeks = now.diff(date, "weeks"),
      result = "";

    if (weeks) {
      result += weeks + (weeks === 1 ? " week " : " weeks ");
      days = days % 7;
    } else if (days || weeks === 0) {
      result += days + (days === 1 ? " day" : " days");
    }

    result += '<br />';
    return result;
  });
});
```

```html
<span class="timestamp">30.07.2018 00:00</span>
<span class="timestamp">12.06.2018 00:00</span>
<span class="timestamp">10.05.2018 00:00</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh nice! And how can I remove the "30.07.2018 - " in front of the "3 days"? If I delete the line "result = date.format("DD.MM.YYYY") + " - ";" it won't work anymore :(

Comment: @MaxDiCampo This way you are removing the declaration of `result`, this will cause errors, you just need to replace `result = date.format("DD.MM.YYYY") + " - "` with `result = ""`. :)

Comment: Perfect! Now I am getting crazy and tried to add hours. So if it is "<= 48 hours", show hours, if ">48 hours" show days... I tried.. but I failed... http://jsfiddle.net/r289hvpL/35/ :S

Comment: You were using a wrong condition, this is an [updated **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/r289hvpL/39/).

Answer (score 19):

Moment.js has fromNow() function that returns "x days" or "x hours ago" from current date/time.

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow();     // 4 years ago
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(true); // 4 years
```

Comment: Any idea how you would get that to output how many days or hours ago that date was rather than the number of years as shown in the example?

Answer (score 1):

```
  const getTime = (date) => {
    let result = moment(date).fromNow();
    const now = moment();
    const days = now.diff(date, 'days');
    const weeks = now.diff(date, 'weeks');
    if (days >= 7) {
      if (days <= 13) {
        result = `a week ago`;
      } else if (days > 13 && days <= 25) {
        result = `${weeks} weeks ago`;
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  getTime("2023-03-07 12:21:51") // 3 days ago
  getTime("2023-02-28 12:21:51") // a week ago
  getTime("2023-02-07 12:21:51") // a month ago
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).